# How to restore only data from a .bak file using SQL Server wizard?

Tags: sql-server, database, restore

Pretty much what the title say. I have tried following the wizard, but I am getting an error saying the server was not found. I probably did not set the variables correctly and it's probably simple enough once you know it, but I was not successful so far...

[The Import/Export Wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGqsJ.png)

Here is the full text of the error:

> TITLE: SQL Server Import and Export Wizard
>
> The operation could not be completed.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)
>
> The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: You want to restore this backup to a different database or a new database?

Comment: To a different DB, with the same tables and structures but with a few new tables and columns

Comment: The error is crystal clear: **cannot find the file specified** ..... so is this for a *remote* server (not on your own machine)? If so, the `.bak` file must be **on that remote server's file system** - not on your machine. The remote server cannot reach onto your local computer's drive to read the `.bak` file (thank goodness!) ....

Comment: I usually restore the full DB from a network drive (.bak file located there), without getting this error. So I didn't expect it to be different/cause an error while trying to just import the data.